# Ionic 2 app safari remote debugger disconnects immediately

Tags: ios, safari, ionic2

I am trying to debug an application written in Ionic 2 (Angular 2) on device via Safari remote dev tools. When the app is open and I connect the iphone to the Mac it shows up under `Safari > Develop` menu, but as soon as I connect to it (and the dev tools do show up) it disappears from the `Safari > Develop` menu and in the just opened dev tools I am unable to execute anything in the console nor expand any node in the Elements panel.

When I unplug and replug the device it shows up in `Safari > Develop` again but the devtools window is gone, and as soon as I open it up again... Same thing.

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You wouldn't believe what solved the issue....

Running Safari.app through terminal by executing `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari` it opened up Safari as usual, but for some strange reason it didn't disconnect my device when connecting to it via remote dev tools.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, unfortunately your workaround doesn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: Wow- this inexplicably also fixed the problem remote-debugging my Cordova app.  Thanks!

Comment: Un-f*cking believable, you're a legend!

Comment: Building without source maps (`ng build --source-map=false`) also fixed it for me but that's a bad solution if you need to debug JS/TS. Running Safari from terminal FTW!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it working in two steps :
First I used to get some debugging console working using ios-webkit-debug-proxy on a linux machine (https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy) (You need to compile from sources including tools from libimobiledevice to get it working with iOS >= 10)

Then it helped me to notice I had many errors like `Refused to load the script 'http://xxxxx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src ...` that where not occurring while remote debugging with android and chrome. Fixed them by adding the appropriates rules in the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="..."` line in index.html . Don't know exactly which one fixed it but is suspect `connect-src wss://s-usc1c-nss-128.firebaseio.com http://my_local_ip:4200 https://maps.googleapis.com ws://*;` did the trick